# How to properly pass data from PHP to JS

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I'd like to store a `Customer` model in a JS variable as JSON. Here are the approaches I tried and the pitfalls I found in each of them:

1. `{{ $customer }}` makes the resulting code in `<script>` look like this: `var customer = {&quot;id&quot;:1, ... &quot;}`, failing with `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &` error. Also, if the variable is `null` in PHP, then in JS it becomes `var customer = ;`, which breaks the code.
2. `{!! $customer !}}` stores the data properly `var customer = {"id":101, ... }`, but it suffers from the same problem as `{{ }}` above when the variable is `null` in PHP.
3. `{!! json_encode($customers->toArray()) !!};` works for a collection, but not for a single model object -- in the latter case PHP would fail by trying to call `toArray()` on null. Also, `{!! !!}` are vulnerable to XSS attacks.

The one that did work for me was `{!! $customer ?? 'undefined' !!}`. It properly handles all cases, but it's haky and insecure. Another solution seems to be `{!! json_encode($customer) !!}` but again, it also suffers from security issues. I wonder if it can be simplified to just `{{ }}`, or maybe there is a better approach.

Thanks!

Comment: Use an ajax request to get either a single `customer`, accessible via `data.customer.id` or a list of `customers`, accessible via `for(var customer in data.customers){ console.log(data.customers[customer].id); }` Or, if you've got a `<script>` code in a `.blade.php` file, it is possible to set a JS variable equal to a php variable, but it's messy, and you should probably avoid too much usage in that sense.

Comment: @Tim Lewis, But what if I am not using restful api design? And plus, it doesn't sound very efficient to re-fetch the data again using Ajax, since I already have this data in PHP/Blade.

Comment: Fair enough, although that begs the question; if you've got the data in PHP/Blade already, what are you trying to do with it in Javascript that requires you to translate it to JS variables? Shouldn't you be creating the HTML based on the PHP and doing your JS based on the HTML?

Comment: @Tim Lewis, Good point, but my JS behavior is dependent on whether certain attributes of a model (i.e. of a row in a table) are non-empty. Thus I need to have access to that model in JS and directly check the values

Comment: Ah, gotcha. In that case, why not loop over the model while in the `<script>` using `blade` syntax and create JS objects from that? `var customers = [ @foreach($customers AS $customer) {id: {{ $customer->id }}, firstName: "{{ $customer->first_name }}"}, @endforeach  ];` You'd then be able to use those customers later in JS without having to constantly switch between php and js syntax.

Comment: @Tim Lewis Thanks for the suggestion. Do you know what the approach would be for a single model object? I.e. you could get either an obj or null when doing `{{ $customer }}`

Comment: `var customer = @if($customer) { id: {{ $customer->id}}, firstName: "{{ $customer->first_name }}" } @else null @endif;` should handle that. (Looks cleaner with indentation, but can't do in comments)

Answer (score 0):

Well that's a little difficult I was trying that time ago, but the only thing that I did (is not the better approach) is this...

I asssigned the values into data tags example

`<input type="hidden" data-customer="{{json_encode(custumer)}}">`

Then I used javascript/JQuery to access to tha info in my script

Comment: This is kinda what I meant in my comment "[...] creating the HTML based on the PHP and doing your JS based on the HTML." Also, syntax error `json_encode(custumer)` should be `json_encode($customer)`.

Answer (score 0):

try isset

```
@if(isset($custumer)){{ $custumer }}@endif
```

Comment: Well, if it's not set, then it would be `var customer = ;` which is a syntax error

Comment: @Alex try `{{ isset($custumer) ? $custumer: 'undefined' }}` and `{{ $custumeror 'undefined' }}` ? hope help

Comment: @GuaHsu How is it different from the one mentioned in the question? Plus, I find hardcoding 'undefined' gross anyway

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this package, which does the magic for you:

https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer